Applying for Computer Science PhD in US after thesis-based MS in Canada
I'm currently doing MS in Computer Science in Canada as an international student and planning to apply for a PhD program in USA after completing my MS.  The reason I chose an MS after BS was that I didn't have enough research experience or publication, which I'm hoping to have through my Master's.  Now my question is: Will it be easier for me to be accepted into a PhD program if I complete the MS program or would the chances have been better if I applied right after undergrad?
I know that it depends.  But I am looking for insight into my situation.  For example, will it affect my application negatively that I applied to a Canadian university for MS but then applying to a US university for PhD?

You say it yourself: answers to this largely depend on individual factors, which is why this question is out of scope here.

It's probably worth mentioning in your application somewhere that in Canada an MSc is not a terminal degree, and is designed to lead into a PhD.

While a Canadian MS won't be a negative factor assuming you do well, neither research experience nor publications are necessary for entry to a US doctoral program.
Whether the chances would have been better along another path depends on how you do in the masters. If you do badly, then yes, it might have been better to apply directly, but you can't change the past.
One option you have is to apply to some programs in the coming application cycle even if you haven't finished the masters. You will need to send transcripts of what you have done there, of course.
Note, importantly, that letters of recommendation that honestly predict your success in a doctoral program are very important for US admissions. They need to come from people who know your work. If you are doing research in the masters then the supervisor would be a good candidate.
